# Specify object type after using ko.mapping.fromJS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

im trying to clone a Knockout VM.
I found some examples doing it by:

```
var oldType = new myVM();
var newType = ko.mapping.fromJS(ko.toJS(oldType));
```

It works fine but `newType` is now an `object` and not `myVM` type as i wanted. is there a way to specify `newType` as `myVM`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer is probably somewhat bias as I don't like the knockout mapping functionality, I think it promotes bad habits.

If I were doing this I would create a constructor on myVM which accepts an instance of myVM as a parameter and then sets all of the properties in the constructor and I'd write the mapping by hand.

That said, you can do what you want with knockout mapping:

```
var oldType = new myVM();
var newType = new myVM();
ko.mapping.fromJS(ko.toJS(oldType), newType);
```

**Edit**
Just checked the knockout docs to refresh my memory and you may actually need to pass the new type as the third parameter, with an empty options object as the second:

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(ko.toJS(oldType), {}, newType);
```

Although the [example page](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) seems to suggest both ways are valid which I doubt.

Comment: I tried this exactly as you wrote. for some reason the newType is empty and didn't got any of the fields of oldType.

Comment: Did you try the edited version with the empty object as the second parameter?

Comment: Yes... Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function

Comment: Strange, I've just created a simple fiddle and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/sv80u5k2/

Comment: You right... well my VM is much more complex i guess it fails due to it's implementation. Thanks any way!

Comment: Sorry, forgot to come back to this this morning.  Is the error on the toJS or fromJS?  If it's on the toJS you can remove it without doing any harm.

Comment: Hi, i just solved it by changing an function in the VM from "pureComputed" to "computed". And it works as i expected! Thanks a lot!